# Run Host code in the same Thread while CUDA Device code is executed

Tags: c++, multithreading, cuda

Is there a way how to run a host code while CUDA device function is running? Due the fact CUDA runtime has to wait until the device function has finished I was wondering if there is a possibility that in the meantime a provided host function delegate would be called.

Something like this:

[image]

Starting a thread before the `<<<function>>>` call is for me not the same [Overhead, ...].

Comment: CUDA device code always asyncronious. Some runtume functions are syncronious, ie CudaDeviceSync, or device memcopy.

Comment: @IvanSolntsev: You mean I have to call my thread function after the `<<<call>>>` and before `CudaDeviceSync()` and then I have what wanted to achieve?

Comment: Basicaly - yes. Not sure how `CudaDeviceSync` behave when device thread is finished before call. You should check CUDA programming guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA kernel calls are *asynchronous*.  This means that control is returned to the host thread that made the kernel call, *before* the kernel actually starts executing.

So you can run host code concurrently with a kernel simply by placing that host code immediately after the kernel call (and before any other CUDA API calls such as `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or `cudaMemcpy()`).  The host code placed there will run concurrently with the kernel, for as long as the kernel executes (and as long as the host code executes.)  If you get to a point in your host code where you need results from the device (kernel), then a non-async CUDA API call such as `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or `cudaMemcpy()` will force the host code (thread) to wait until the previously issued CUDA activity (kernels) are complete.

You may wish to read about [asynchronous concurrent execution](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) in the programming guide.